# Why does this GLSL code compile and link even though it has a syntax error?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have a GLSL fragment shader with an intentional syntax error.

```
void main()
{
    // vec4 is ommitted
    gl_FragColor = (1,1,0,1);
}
```

But I can still compile and link it without errors. After running my application
I see nothing on the screen. Is this an odd behavior or something else?

Comment: I edited the question to try to format the question a bit better. Feel free to roll back/edit the changes if you think it was too much.

Comment: Which `#version` is your shader, and what are you running it on?  (I get "implicit cast from int to vec4" for "#version 130" on an NVidia desktop GPU....)

Comment: GLSL version : 3.3 , OS : Ubuntu 12.04LTS , graphics card : ATI Radeon 4650

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have used the comma operator.

Your code evaluates each of the comma separated number and discards them all except for the last one so it's equivalent to writing

```
gl_FragColor = (1);
```

where the parentheses is just for grouping, not a function call so can be ignored. When you assign a single value to a vector it replicates that value to all the components so your statement is the same as writing -

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(1,1,1,1);
```

Is the "background" white? In which case you'll see nothing.

Comment: No. Background color is black.

Comment: _When you assign a single value to a vector it replicates that value to all the components ..._. Actually, the GLSL specifications don't mention this, and this also doesn't work on ATi cards. NVidia however seems to ignore the specs and the code does work as you describe.

Comment: Hmm I checked this in the spec before posting as I wasn't sure... At least I thought I did... Checking :)

Comment: I found this "5.4.2 Vector and Matrix Constructors
Constructors can be used to create vectors or matrices from a set of scalars, vectors, or matrices. This 
includes the ability to shorten vectors.
If there is a single scalar parameter to a vector constructor, it is used to initialize all components of the 
constructed vector to that scalar’s value."

Comment: @jcoder I don't think implicit constructors are supported, so the section 5.4.2 applies to `gl_FragColor = vec4(1);` not `gl_FragColor = 1;`.

Comment: @P.T. Ok, I'll take your word for that, I'm not an expert at this.  It would explain the original question too though, if it's setting a simple value that isn't replicated though.